# Subject for custom UIActivity

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiactivityviewcontroller

How do I specify that a custom `UIActivity` supports a subject?

The documentation for the [UIActivityItemSource](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIActivityItemSource_protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIActivityItemSource/activityViewController:subjectForActivityType:) protocol mentions that you can implement the optional `activityViewController:subjectForActivityType:` selector, if you want you source to provide a subject:

> When posting an item the service may provide for a separate subject field and data field, such as an email message. Implement this method if you wish to provide a subject field for services that support one.

But, as far as I can tell, it isn't documented anywhere how I might actually specify that my custom UIActivity supports a subject. How is this done?

**Edit: To make my question clearer**

Assume I have a custom activity item source, say `DocumentActivityItemSource` which implements the `UIActivityItemSource` protocol, and I have a custom `UIActivity`, which we can call `SendWithFooMessageActivity`.

I then start a UIActivtyViewController:

```
NSArray *activityItems = @[[[DocumentActivityItemSource alloc] initWithDocument: document]];
NSArray *applicationActivities = @[[[SendWithFooMessageActivity alloc] init]];
UIActivityViewController *activityViewController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:activityItems
                                                                                     applicationActivities:applicationActivities];
[parentViewController presentViewController:activityViewController
                                   animated:YES
                                 completion:nil];
```

Now, in the popup I select the `SendWithFooMessageActivity`. The activity controller will then call `activityViewController:itemForActivityType:` on the `DocumentActivityItemSource` instance to get an item, which it will then forward to the `SendWithFooMessageActivity` by calling that objects `prepareWithActivityItems:` method.

Normaly the activity item would be an image, a string or a url. In this case, let's say that the `DocumentActivityItemSource` returns a string with an exiting blurb about the document. The `SendWithFooMessageActivity` can then use this text as the body text of it's foo-mail message.

However, a Foo message also requires a subject to be valid. Interestingly enough the `UIActivityItemSource` protocol also contains the optional `activityViewController:subjectForActivityType:` which is in fact documented to provide a subject to services that supports one.

For the Apple provided email activity this does in fact happen - `activityViewController:subjectForActivityType:` is called on the `DocumentActivityItemSource` and the result is used in the email as subject.

There does not seem to be, however, a way to specify that my custom `SendWithFooMessageActivity` would also like to get the subject from the activityitem? The documentation mentions that this happens for "services that supports [a subject]" - so then how do I specify that my service does in fact support one.

Also, the same goes for the `activityViewController:thumbnailImageForActivityType:suggestedSize:`, which is supposed to provide a thumbnail to "services that supports one". This works for the default ShareOnTwitter and ShareOnFacebook activies, but there does not seem to be a way to get custom activites to support it. Is this possible?

So far I have used the workaround that @chriszumberge is also providing below, which is to short-circuit the activityViewController and directly initialize the custom activity with the information it needs from the itemsource:

```
[SendWithFooMessageActivity alloc] initWithSubject: document.title];
```

But this does not seem to be the way that the whole `UIActivityViewController` setup is supposed to be used.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend:

```
UIActivityViewController *activityVC = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] 
    initWithActivityItems:@[@"Info you're emailing out."] applicationActivities:nil];
[activityVC setValue:@"Custom Email Subject Here" forKey:@"subject"];
```

However, since you're using a custom `UIActivity` and appear to be using email, I'm going to assume you're using `MFMailComposeViewController` to send the email.

In that case I would create a property in your custom `UIActivityItemProvider` for the subject string, and set it in which ever method you init your custom `UIActivity`and pass it to the `UIActivityViewController`. In the provider you can create a dictionary and set the subject string for any key value you wish in the

`- (id)activityViewController:(UIActivityViewController *)activityViewController itemForActivityType:(NSString *)activityType`

method.

From there, in your custom `UIActivity` you can store your subject as a property from the dictionary in the `- (UIViewController*) activityViewController` method, and in that same method use the code below to initialize the email and set the subject.

```
MFMailComposeViewController *mailCVC = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
mailCVC.mailComposeDelegate = self;
[mailCVC setSubject:theSubject];
[mailCVC setMessageBody:theMessage isHTML:NO];
[mailCVC addAttachmentData:theData mimeType:@"text/csv" fileName:theFileName];
```

**EDIT**

The `UIActivityItemProvder` protocol defines methods used by a UIActivityViewController object to retrieve the data items to act on (straight from apple documentation). 
The `activityViewController:subjectForActivityType:` method is part of the `UIActivityItemSource` protocol.

Your custom `UIActivityItemProvider` conforms to the `UIActivityItemSource` protocol by default. That's where you need to implement the `subjectForActivityType:` method.

You can then use either a `switch/case` statement or a bunch of `if` statements to determine whether the incoming `[activityType isEqualToString:@"Custom UIActivity Title"]` defined in the custom UIActivity's `activityTitle` method.
If so, then return whatever the subject string should be.
But this needs to be in your custom `UIActivityItemProvider` subclass.

Comment: This is also exactly what I have been doing, but it seems like a kludge since the protocol seemingly includes support for both subjects and thumbnails. I am confused as to why it isn't possible for a custom UIActivity to get these - seems like a flaw or oversight from Apple.

Comment: @AHM- I may be misunderstanding your statement, but it is not possible for a custom UIActivity to use the `activityViewController:subjectForActivityType:` selector, **unless** you make your custom UIActivity conform to the [UIActivityItemSource protocol](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIActivityItemSource_protocol/index.html).

Comment: Maybe I am misunderstanding something. Would a `UIActivity` implement the `UIActivityItemSource`? As far as I understand it your custom UIActivities should inherit from the base `UIActivity` and your activity items should implement the `UIActivityItemSource` protocol. You would then register both the items and the custom activites on the UIActivityViewController, and that would then ask the user to pick an activity, and configure the chosen one with the provided items. What I am asking is how to specifiy that my custom `UIActivity` wants to be configured with a subject.

Comment: What I was trying to say was you cannot (easily) use `activityViewController:subjectForActivityType:` on a `UIActivity`.. in fact you probably shouldn't.
Too much to type in a comment box, see my edits above.

Comment: Yeah, well, I know that - what you write in your edit is what I tried to describe above. I will try to edit my post as well, to make my question clearer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's an automated way of doing that.

Instead, you would just manually call the protocol method on the source item to get the subject. You would do that either on the `activityViewController` code or on on the `-(void)performActivity` method.

For safety, you can check if it's implemented first:

```
NSString *subject = nil;
if ([item respondsToSelector:@selector(activityViewController:subjectForActivityType:)]
{
     subject = [item activityViewController:activityViewController subjectForActivityType:activityType];
}
```

Comment: How are you implementing the protocol? I don't think the UIActivity normally would get access to the raw UIActivityItemSource. As far as I understand it, the UIActivityItemSource is supposed to return an item from activityViewController:itemForActivityType: and that item should be an NSString, UIImage, UIImage, or something else depending on what you want to share.

Are you sure that you can just return the UIActivityItemSource as an item? Can you get that to work the the default Apple-provided activites for mail, Twitter and Facebook?